# Input full sentence from .txt file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, file-io

I am writing a program that needs to sort quotes from a .txt file and output to a different file. The QUOTES.txt file I am trying to put into an array to sort has quotes like this

> If you would hit the mark, you must aim a little above it; every arrow that
>     flies feels the attraction of earth.  Henry Wadsworth Longfellow
>
> Never, never, never give up!   Winston Churchill
>
> Great works are performed not by strength but by perseverance.
>      Samuel Johnson
>
> More people fail through lack of purpose than lack of talent.  Billy Sunday
>
> Children have never been very good at listening to their elders, but they
>      have never failed to imitate them.  James Baldwin

Without having to change my template, is there a way to sort the full sentences? Right now it is inputting the words individually and sorts the words but I would like the sentences to stay intact and only sort by the first letter of the sentence. Here is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template < typename T >
T sorting(T rays [], int size)
{
    int minIndx, i;
    T temp;

    for (int passCount = 0; passCount < size - 1; passCount++)
    {
        minIndx = passCount;

        for (int searchIndx = passCount + 1; searchIndx < size; searchIndx++)
            if (rays[searchIndx] < rays[minIndx])
                minIndx = searchIndx;

        temp = rays[minIndx];
        rays[minIndx] = rays[passCount];
        rays[passCount] = temp;
    }

    cout << endl << "Sorted:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << rays[i] << endl;

    cout << endl;

    return (0);
}

int main()
{

    ifstream inNumbers("IntFile.txt");
    ifstream inFloaters("FloatFile.txt");
    ifstream inWords("QUOTES.txt");
    ofstream outNumbers("SortedInt.txt");
    ofstream outFloaters("SortedFloat.txt");
    ofstream outWords("SortedQuotes.txt");

    int i, length = 0, lengt = 0, leng = 0;
    int data[100];
    double data2[100];
    string data3[100];

    if (!inNumbers)
    {
        cerr << "IntFile.txt file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!inFloaters)
    {
        cerr << "FloatFile.txt file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!inWords)
    {
        cerr << "QUOTES.txt file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100 && inNumbers; ++i)
    {
        inNumbers >> data[i];
        if (inNumbers)
        {
            length += 1;
        }
    }

    sorting(data, length);

    for (i = 0; i < 100 && inFloaters; ++i)
    {
        inFloaters >> data2[i];
        if (inFloaters)
        {
            lengt += 1;
        }
    }

    sorting(data2, lengt); 

    for (i = 0; i < 100 && inWords; ++i)
    {
        inWords >> data3[i];
        if (inWords)
        {
            leng += 1;
        }
    }

    sorting(data3, leng);
}
```

----------EDIT---------------

I changed the input for `inWords` from `inWords >> data3[i];` to `getline(inWords, data3[i];` so now it scans one line at a time. Now I just need to find out how to sort this new array and still keeping the quotes intact.

Comment: What abour std:: vector instead of array?

Comment: Why not get the entire quote into one string and then sort?  You can use `getline()` for an entire line of string input.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: I do not know anything about std::vector. How could I use getline() for quotes being inputted from a .txt file? I thought that was only for strings entered into the keyboard.

Comment: @StephenOsborne Look up `std::getline`, `std::istringstream` and `operator >>` associated with it if you want to both have the string and at the same time store the individual words.

Comment: @StephenOsborne BTW, why are you learning templates, but not using `std::sort` to do the sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't bother incorporating the solution into your existing code, but this definitely works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream iFile("QUOTES.txt");
    assert(iFile.is_open());

    vector<string> quoteLines, quotes;

    for (string s; getline(iFile, s);) quoteLines.push_back(s);

    iFile.close();

    /* deal with multi-line quotes by merging the stuff separated
     by empty lines into single strings */
    string tmpStr;
    for (const auto& s : quoteLines) {
        if (s == "") {
            /* if we come across an empty line, put the stuff we had so far into the vector
             and clear the temporary string */
            quotes.push_back(tmpStr);
            tmpStr.clear();
        } else {
            /* if there's already stuff in the temporary string, then append a space to it. */
            /* then, append the current line */
            tmpStr += ((tmpStr.size() == 0)?"":" ") + s;
        }
    }

    /* sort the quotes */
    sort(quotes.begin(), quotes.end());

    for (const auto& s : quotes) cout << s << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```